# Detect if logged in user is network active directory user or local user

Tags: macos, user-account, network-user

When a User logs in to os x , I want to detect if user is a local user or a network account user based on which I have to allow my app to run.

Couldn't find any solution which tells that current logged in user is a network account user or local created account user.